# lpr: Error - unknown option "V"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, printing, cups, lpr

I am getting this error when trying to run the lpr command:

> lpr: Error - unknown option "V".

My full command I am running is

```
lpr -V -P printer-1 file.txt
```

According to the documentation here http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man1/lpr.1.html there is a `-V` flag.

If I run the command without the `-V` flag it prints fine, however I need output so the application I am building knows if the print was successful or not.

Running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

UPDATE #1

I tried this again on Ubuntu 14.04 and it still does not recognise the `-V` flag.
As @smagnan pointed out, CUPS does not support the `-V` flag.

So, is there a Linux distribution that does not use CUPS and uses another printing system which does have a verbose flag? A success or fail output is imperative for the application.

Comment: Have you just tried changing th flags ordre? like: `lpr -P printer-1 file.txtn -V` Maybe ask on askubuntu.com anyway

Comment: @smagnan I have tried a different order

Answer (score 1):

Sadly it seems that:

> The "c", "d", "f", "g", "i", "m", "n", "t", "v", and "w" options **are
>   not supported** by *CUPS* and will produce a warning message if used.

Source: [linux man page for lpr](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/lpr.1.php)

Note: *CUPS* means Common Unix Printing System which is used in ubuntu it seems:
http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/impression_sous_ubuntu

Comment: Are there alternatives to CUPS on Ubuntu?

Comment: Or a different Linux distribution which does have output for printing?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know much about all of that (printing commands on unix/linux/ubuntu)... as said before you may have more chance asking on http://askubuntu.com/ (or even http://unix.stackexchange.com/)